# http can not return html content in angular 4

Tags: html, angular

I am working on angular4, trying to load a html template into the page.

```
this.http.get("/assets/abc.html")
  .subscribe(
    (data) => {
      console.log("--------------"+data);
    }
  );
```

The result of the http returns me not the html content but only the page path shown as below

```
--------------Response with status: 200 OK for URL: http://localhost:4200/assets/abc2.html
```

how to get the real content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you get there in the subscription is Response object. To get the actual data, try this:

```
this.http.get("/assets/abc.html")
  .subscribe(
    (response) => {
      console.log(response.text());
    }
  );
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, same here

Answer (score 3):

Extract the content of the response with :

```
this.http.get("/assets/abc.html")
  .subscribe( res => {
      console.log(res.text());
    }
  );
```